# return url is null, how to get it

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I'm trying to get the returnURL but probably I'm missing something. The webconfig is:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/UserAccount/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <allow users="?" />
</authorization>
```

part of LogIn.cshtml is:

```
@model Models.UserModel

@{
// ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogIn", "UserAccount", new { ReturnUrl =   Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>
        <table>
```

and part of the LogIn method is:

```
  [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult LogIn(string ReturnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = ReturnUrl;
        var model = new UserModel();
        return View(model);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogIn(UserModel model, string returnUrl)
    {            
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
```

I thought that is everything that I have to do get returnURL to the LogIn method but is is not working. What I'm doing wrong? 
Thanks.

Comment: ReturnUrl will be null of your are going to page `LogIn` indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

I did not know that custom authorize attribute plays vital role in the process so I made changes in:

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {

        filterContext.Result = new System.Web.Mvc.RedirectResult("/UserAccount/LogIn/?ReturnUrl=" + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
```

and now it is working.